# How are places like Refinery29 customizing their share controls?

Tags: facebook, plugins, twitter, social-networking

I've seen a lot of sites that have customized Twitter, Facebook, Pinterest (etc) social controls that show the widget's count in a special style. I can't find any of these services explicitly offering support for count scraping outside of a locked-down, on-brand button. How are people working around this?

For example, Refinery29 shows their social counts inside of a self-designed bubble.

Comment: The Facebook Like button on refinery29.com looks pretty standard to me … so what do you actually mean …?

Comment: Apart from the Facebook Like button, it does not look like they using external “plugins” there to display the other social share buttons, but just their own HTML elements. So most likely they are just getting the actual counter values for twitter and pinterest via their respective APIs in the background.